# Docker image size increases when pulled from docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

I did `docker pull tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask` and this image size in docker hub is 345MB but when I pulled it to my local it increased to 963 MB.

So, Below are my questions:

1. Will docker image size increases when is it being pulled?
2. Is there any way to reduce or get the actual size as an image in the docker hub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dockerhub` compresses each layer in the image and store it.

For example: https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags

See the **COMPRESSED SIZE** tag on each image and it says:

> This size is calculated by summing the image's layers, of which are compressed.

#### Is there any way to reduce or get the actual size as an image in the docker hub?

If you want to work with the `image` or create `containers` from it then the `image` has to be uncompressed. **Docker** controls this behaviour IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your response.